# Using json object values with PHP variables

Tags: php, json, javascript-objects

I have a URL giving output a json object as: 
http://sachasauda.net/webservices/web_services_request/youtube_url?variable_name=test

its giving output on page is :

```
test={"name":"youtube_live_url","value":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=xCjeLHoqdis"}
```

i want to use test.value, but i dont know, how it can be used in php code as variable 
or how can i assign test.value to a php variable.

I will appreciate any kind of help

Comment: Do this.. `echo json_decode($test,true)['value'];` The demo.. https://eval.in/137730

Comment: You need to remove the `test=` from the beginning, then it will be valid JSON.

Comment: @dvdowns That doesn't look like PHP. I'm not sure what question you're answering, he never said anything about calling the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave off the `variable_name=test` parameter. Then it returns ordinary JSON, rather than a Javascript statement. Then you can call `json_decode()` on the result.

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://sachasauda.net/webservices/web_services_request/youtube_url");
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
$value = $obj['value'];
echo $value;
```

Comment: @barmar thanks for your answer but its giving error: Warning: file_get_contents() [<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in G:\wamp\www\Practice_Php\test-json.php on line 21

Comment: It works fine for me. I don't know why your system can't look up the hostname. Make sure you don't have a typo in the URL.

Comment: @barmar , it working now, problem was at my end
Regards & Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to fetch page content :

```
$page = file_get_contents('http://sachasauda.net/webservices/web_services_request/youtube_url');
$json_obj=trim($page);
// convert json to array 
$result_array=json_decode($json, true);
echo $result_array['value'];
```

And also can be done through CURL :

```
$url = 'http://sachasauda.net/webservices/web_services_request/youtube_url';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
$result=json_decode($data,true);
echo $result['value'];
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: @Rajveer thanks brother for your answer. its also giving error:  Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in G:\wamp\www\Practice_Php\test-json.php on line 22

Comment: @sssuri curl extension that needs to be installed.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.setup.php

Comment: @Rajveer yes Brother i Have Installed , Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
// remove ?variable_name=test from link
$page = file_get_contents('http://sachasauda.net/webservices/web_services_request/youtube_url');
$json = json_decode($page);

var_dump($json);
```

Comment: This is already been replied by @Barmar